# Matlab, Cannot get fgoalattain to work to save my life

Tags: matlab

I cannot get fgoalattain to work to save my life. It just comes with the following errors that I have not figured out how to fix despite several hours of messing with the highlighted areas. The issues with interpolation work fine until I use fgolattain and the fgoalattain is used as specified in documentation.

Help?

> Error using griddedInterpolant The number of input coordinate arrays
>   does not equal the number of dimensions (NDIMS) of these arrays.
>
> Error in Scan (line 5) F = griddedInterpolant(xx',yy',a','cubic'); %
>   Prepare image for interpolation
>
> Error in @(vals)Scan(vals,xx,yy,nr,m,d)
>
> Error in goalcon (line 63)
>                   f = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});
>
> Error in fgoalattain (line 399)
>           [ctmp,ceqtmp] = feval(cfun{3},xnew,extravarargin{:});
>
> Error in Cu (line 24) xz =
>   fgoalattain(@(vals)Scan(vals,xx,yy,nr,m,d),x0,goal,weight);

```
clear all; 
close all; 
clc 

% Create ring
x = -31:31;
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,x);        % 2-D arrays with x and y-coord. respectively    
r = sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2)/31;       % Distance to center of grid
a = 2*exp(max(-40.0,-6000.0*(r-0.7).^4)).*(1.1-0.75*yy/31.0);
a = a/max(max(a));              % Normalize a so in range [0,1]

% Create the scan. This time specify size as desired     
nr = 60;                        % Number of rays for each angle
m  = 66;                        % Number of angles to use

%scan function
sc = Scan(a,xx,yy,nr,m);

%applying optimization tool
x0 = rand();
goal = sc;
weight = abs(sc);
xz = fgoalattain(@(vals)Scan(vals,xx,yy,nr,m),x0,goal,weight);

figure
mesh(xz)
drawnow

figure
pcolor(xz)
drawnow
```

with Scan function written as:

```
function [ sc ] = Scan( a, xx, yy, nr, m)

d = zeros(nr,m);                % Array to hold the scan vectors
xt = linspace(-31,31,nr); 
[xx1,yy1] = meshgrid(xt,xt);
F = griddedInterpolant(xx',yy',a','cubic'); % Prepare image for interpolation

for j=0:m-1                     % Loop over m angles
   th = pi*j/m; st = sin(th); ct = cos(th);
   xr = xx1*ct-yy1*st;           % Generate the x1,x2-coordinates for
   yr = xx1*st+yy1*ct;           % the grid points in the xp1,xp2 grid.
   s  = F(xr',yr')';             % Interpolate
   d(:,j+1) = sum(s,2);         % Sum along each ray
end
  sc = d/max(max(d));           % Normalize so max value = 1.

end
```

Comment: I don't get how you don't have a "Not enough input arguments" error when calling `Scan`: it's defined to have 6 input variables, only 5 provided. **Edit**: your error messages give you away. **Please make sure to include the exact code that you actually use.**

Comment: Sry about that. When i was posting i was messing with some things still. the extra variable was one of those things, guess i forgot to edit it in the stack overflow code..

Comment: I suggest copying this version of the code and rerunning, and changing the error messages accordingly. You can never know that "messing around" didn't remove your original problem or introduced new ones.

Comment: Code is exact for above error messages now. Its obvious that the code is making to fgoalattain aspect and that the issues are spawning there.

Comment: Don't tell me that it prints `Error in @(vals)Scan(vals,xx,yy,nr,m,d)` with your above script. If it does: restart matlab and try again.

Comment: Yes it does. I just restarted. Continues to provide that error. Yes the above code is correct. I copied it in without any additions just to double check i wasnt missing anything small.

Comment: Applied it to another computer. Still have same exact errors

Comment: You really, *really*, **really** get an error which contains `d` as the last variable in `Scan`?

Comment: No the d's are removed from the error messages. However the error messages are the same. Aka the problem persists. The issue I think is that when the fgoalattain tries to input potential values for variable vals its not passing it the correct sized matrix. However, I cannot define x0 directly as x0 = ones(60:66) returns another error that says you cannot have this large of a matrix as it is 29000GB and this exceeds matlabs memory. I think If i overcome this, it will solve the NDIM issues.

Comment: `ones(60:66)` means `ones([60 61 62 63 64 65 66])` which is clearly not what you mean, hence the large size. You mean `ones(60,66)`, but I don't think that's your problem: `x0` seems to be allowed to be a scalar. Have you considered transforming your variables to vectors using `reshape`? `fgoalattain` seems to assume input vectors, converting matrices to vectors if those are supplied.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change it either. Same error. If I alter the varibles x0, goal, or weight such that it doesnt work with fgoalattain i get an error that prevents the arguments from being inputs into the optimization tool. So i dont think its my inputs directly that are causing the issue, rather i think its the vals variable being generated by the optimization tool that is inputting inproper dimensions into the interpolation generator which is causing the issue. However, Im not sure how to alter  the dimensions given by the fgoalattain, as it is solving for vals and that's the whole point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it guesses the dimension from `goal`, since that is your `goal`. You should try checking the dimensions of all your arrays for surprises, maybe look through them all using `whos`.

Comment: Im not finding anything. When running the code and graphing the results prior to fgoalattain it works fine. Its only fails when optimizing /= sigh.